# How add wpf image button?

Tags: css, wpf, mvvm

Hi i am developing WPF application using MVVM and i am try to add image as a button (like windows 8 start page button) Is there a way to have a Button only display as an image? I have an image that i would like to use as a button alone, but I can't seem to get the Button borders to go away and the Button background color to become transparent. or any way to use image as a Button ? Help me

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}"  Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" 
      x:Name="New" Cursor="Hand" FontWeight="ExtraBold" 
      Margin="10,22,102,5" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

  <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/NewIcon.png"
           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Width="145" Height="93"  />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just replace the default `Button ControlTemplate` with a plain `Image` control. Try this:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" Width="16" Height="16">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Stretch="None" 
Source="pack://application:,,,/AppName;component/FolderName/ImageName.png" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```